# Error occurred during initialization of boot layer java.lang.module.FindException: Module java.fxml not found

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to run a Java Project cloned from github but I'm getting this error on my console:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer java.lang.module.FindException: Module java.fxml not found
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

So I actually found the bug! It was a spelling error on my VM arguments.
Here's how I changed my module path to:

```
--module-path /home/tindi/Documents/javafx-sdk-19/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml
```